# Problema al intentar sumar los meses de ganancia de mi empresa, lenguaje C

Tags: array, c

sigo trabajando en el mismo codigo de ayer y pude avanzar y comprender muchas cosas que antes no entendia, pero ahora, estoy trabado hace unas horas con una parte del enunciado.
Pide calcular las ganancias anuales de cada empresa, y tambien calcular las ganancias mensuales de las empresas (Todas juntas), no se como hacerlo ya que no tengo tanta experiencia con las matrices

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESES 12

void cargarNombreYApellido (char[]);
void crearContrasenia (char[], char[]);
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(void); //Esta función NO ACEPTA PARÁMETROS.
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int, float[][MESES]);
void mostrarVector(int, float [][MESES]);
void gananciaPorMes(int, float[][MESES]);
void gananciaAnual(int, float[][MESES]);

//#############################################################
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    char nombre[100];
    char apellido[100];

    cargarNombreYApellido(nombre);

    printf("Te llamas %s ", nombre);




    char password[200];
    crearContrasenia(nombre,password);

    //########################################################
    printf("Bienvenido\n\n");
    printf("Tu usuario es %s\n", nombre);
    printf("Tu contrasenia es %s\n", password);

    int cantEmpresas = elegirCantidadDeEmpresas();
    float empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
    cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas);
    mostrarVector(cantEmpresas, empresas);

    gananciaPorMes(cantEmpresas, empresas);

    return 0;
}
//##############################################################


void cargarNombreYApellido (char nombre[100])
{
    printf("Introduce tu nombre y tu apellido = ");
    gets(nombre);

    fflush(stdin);



}

void crearContrasenia (char nombre[100], char password[200])
{
    int tamNombre=strlen(nombre); //Obtengo la cantidad de caracteres para usar en el for
    strcpy(password,nombre); //Copia el valor de nombre a la variable password

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<tamNombre; i++)
    {
        if (password[i]=='a' || password[i]=='e' || password[i]=='i' || password[i]=='o' || password[i]=='u')
        {
            password[i]='x';
        }

        if (password[i]=='A' || password[i]=='E' || password[i]=='I' || password[i]=='O' || password[i]=='U')
        {
            password[i]='X';
        }

    }
    system("cls");

}
/*Elegir con cuantas empresas quiere trabajar el usuario, mayor a 3*/

int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas()
{
    int cantEmpresas;
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
    while(cantEmpresas<3){
        printf("Mayor a 3\nIntroduce el valor = ");
        cantEmpresas=0;
        scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
        }


    return cantEmpresas;
}

void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i,k;
    int n;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < MESES; k++)

            empresas[i][k]= ((float) (-10000 +rand()%(60001))/100);
    }
}

void mostrarVector(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i;
    int k;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++)
        {
            printf("%.2f  ###  ", empresas[i][k]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void gananciaPorMes(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]){
    int i; //uso para cada mes de empresa
    int k; //uso para anio
    int ganancia; //Creo que esta mal inicializada
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++){
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++){
            ganancia+=empresas[i][k]; //Aca estaria sumando todas las ganancias de las empresas y guardandolas en la variable Ganancias

        }
    }
    printf("Ganancia total de las empresas = \n\n%d", ganancia);
}
void gananciaAnual(int cantempresas, float empresas[][MESES]){ //Ganancia anual de cada empresa
 int i;
 int k;
 int ganancia;

  for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++){
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++){
            ganancia+=empresas[i][k]; //Aca necesito meter una sola empresa, no todas las columnas, no se como hacerlo

        }
    }
}
```

La parte final del codigo esta muy confusa, no se como puedo lograrlo
Por si no se entendio, lo que yo necesito hacer es sumar columna por columna (de izquierda a derecha) los valores, que son 12 (uno por mes), pero lo unico que se hacer es sumar todo junto, ¿Qué hago o como se puede realizar?
Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: y si pones en cero las ganancias despues de sumar todas las columnas de una fila?

Comment: Es una buena idea, pero solamente estaria sumando una columna, no podria avanzar a la siguiente fila

Comment: y si tenes una estructura que pueda guardar un monton de valores en cada fila.. digamos un array?

Comment: No entiendo, a que te referis?

Comment: tenes una matriz.. cada fila es una empresa.. y cada columna un mes.. digamos para simplificar, que si agregas una columna mas podrias sumar el total ahi no??? o podrias tener un vector, donde cada fila fuera la misma empresa que en la matriz.. y en su contenido, guardar la suma mensual.. no?

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema. Sí te piden esto: *Pide calcular las ganancias anuales de cada empresa...* Es porque debes calcular de forma separada las ganancias de cada empresa, simplemente puedes usar el mismo código que tienes en `gananciaPorMes`e imprimir el total de ganancias cuando el bucle anidado finalice. Otra opción sería guardar las ganancias de cada empresa en un array y luego mostrarlo por pantalla..

Comment: @HatoriHanso a lo que se refiere gbianchi es que si tienes una matriz (con filas y columnas), y quieres sumar las columnas, te va a quedar un array con la suma de cada columna. Es decir una matriz de 5x5 se reduciría a un array de 5x1, donde cada elemento del array es la suma total de todos los elementos de una columna. Se entiende mejor si lo dibujas.

Comment: @MrDave1999 muchas gracias por responder en cada post que hago, agradezco demasiado, pero no logro comprender, intentare dibujar para ver si se me ocurre algo

Comment: @HatoriHanso He dejado una respuesta, espero te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un if dentro del bucle para  comprobar si el valor: k=12, cuando k tenga ese valor, la variable ganancia será igual a los valores de una sola fila, tal como dices. Así pues solo bastaría salir del bucle cuando se de la condición.

Comment: Considero esta respuesta de baja calidad, pienso que deberías de mejorarla. **Es una recomendación.**

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score 0):

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** Nunca inicializas la variable `ganancia`. Su valor por defecto debería ser `0`.

**2.-** El tipo de dato de la variable `ganancia` debe ser de tipo `float` y no `int`. Esto se debe porque la matriz contiene elementos de tipo `float`.

Siguiendo con las observaciones, la función `gananciaPorMes` quedaría así:

```c
void gananciaPorMes(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i; 
    int k; 
    float ganancia = 0; 
    for (i=0; i < cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k=0; k < MESES; k++)
            ganancia += empresas[i][k]; 
    }
    printf("Ganancia total de las empresas = \n\n %f", ganancia);
}
```

Sí lo que interesa es mostrar la ganancia anual de cada empresa, lo puedes hacer cuando el bucle anidado finalice:

```c
void gananciaAnual(int cantempresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{ 
    int i;
    int k;
    float ganancia = 0;

  for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
  {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++)
            ganancia += empresas[i][k]; 
        printf("Ganancia anual de la empresa %d fue de %f\n", i + 1, ganancia);
        ganancia = 0; //Inicializamos a 0, para la siguiente cálculo.
    }
}
```